# Spring MVC 3 Locale changing using a link not working

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-3

Edit: My Spring framework version 3.0.5

A small issue here, The language is not changing when I click the language changer link.

The language files (messages_xx.properties) are in the classpath i18n directory. The files are:

```
i18n/messages_en.properties
i18n/messages_ar.properties
```

Spring Configuration

```
<!-- Component scanner. This is used to automatically find Spring annotations like @Service and @Repository -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.keype" />

    <!-- Annotation driven programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />   
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />


    <!-- Session Object Configuration -->
    <bean id="session" class="com.keype.system.Session" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>

    <!-- The View Resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"
          />

    <!-- i18n Configuration. Default language is english. Change language using ?language=en -->
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Message text files. This is set UTF-8 to display Arabic UTF correctly. -->    
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

A section from the JSP Code

```
<a href="?lang=ar"><spring:message code="header.arabic" /></a> | 
    <a href="?lang=en"><spring:message code="header.english" /></a>
```

The issue is, when I click the above link to change the language, the locale changing functionality is not working. I tested by changing the "defaultLocate" to "ar" and I'm getting Arabic text.

What could possibly be wrong here? There is nothing in the tomcat log also.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to register the *localeChangeInterceptor* among the MVC interceptors for Spring-MVC to consider it. Add the interceptor to the configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
        </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I tried it now. But I'm getting exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ref'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":interceptor}' is expected. By the way, it's strange nowhere in any tutorial I referred mentioned about a interceptor registration. Any thoughts?

Comment: And I tried this too:  <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
No luck

Comment: You are right, the <ref/> element is not allowed. ¿did you include the lang param as shown in the edited answer?

Comment: That's it ! It's working now. I think this configuration is an overhead and should be part of the defaults. Hope someone brings this up. Thank you Pau. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
        p:paramName="lang" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that can help others:

In my case, I MUST add  in the applicationContext.xml. Putting it in the spring-servlet (ref. dispatcher), not worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the LocaleChangeInterceptor inside the mvc interceptors tag as below,

E.g.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="siteLanguage" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I was getting the same error and it worked using this code :-)

Comment: Please [do not post images as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Copy it into the post and use the markdown code formatting to format it correctly (the "{}" button).

Comment: Yes, Thank you @MihaiChelaru :)